# Issue with createQueryBuilder and MongoRegex

Tags: php, json, mongodb, symfony

After several research for the createquerybuilder for mongodb, I cannot solve my issue.Can you please help me?
Here is the structure of the data :

```
“Field1” : { “Field2”: “value1a”,“Field3” : {“Field4” : “value2a”,”Field5” : “value3a”}}
“Field1” : { “Field2”: “value1b”,“Field3” : {“Field4” : “value2b”,”Field5” : “value3b”}}
“Field1” : { “Field2”: “value1c”,“Field3” : {“Field4” : “value2c”,”Field5” : “value3c”}}
```

How can I get the whole row where Field5 = value3a ?
I have proceeded with the below code but it doesn’t return me any record :

```
$keywords = "test";
$keywords_Array = explode(',',$keywords);
$nbKeyword = count($keywords_Array);
$odm = $this->get("doctrine mongodb");
$donnees =  $odm->createQueryBuilder("MyBundle:MyCollection");
for($i=0; $i<$nbKeyword; $i++){
$search = new \MongoRegex('/"Field5":"'.$ keywords_Array [$i].'"/');
$donnees = $donnees->field("Field1")->equals(new \MongoRegex('/"Field3":"'.$search.'"/'));
}
$donnees = $donnees->getQuery()->execute();
Foreach($donnees  as $ data)
{
$resp = $data->getResult();
}
Return $resp;
```

And another structure of data (here, the data is an array of values):

```
“Field1” : {“Field2”: [“value1”,”value2”,”value3”]}
```

How can I get the whole row where Field2 = value3 ?
It is the same as above with the below code, it doesn’t return me any record :

```
 $keywords = "test";
 $keywords_Array = explode(',',$keywords);
 $nbKeyword = count($keywords_Array);
 $odm = $this->get("doctrine mongodb");
 $donnees =  $odm->createQueryBuilder("MyBundle:MyCollection");
 for($i=0; $i<$nbKeyword; $i++){                     
     $donnees = $donnees-> field("Field1")->equals(new \MongoRegex('/"Field2":"'. $keywords_Array [$i].'"/i'));
            }
 $donnees = $donnees->getQuery()->execute();
 Foreach($donnees  as $ data)
 {
$resp = $data->getResult();
 }
 Return $resp;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The issue is fixed.I post the solution just in case anyone have the same problem :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed.I post the solution just in case anyone has also the same problem.
For the first structure of data, the code should be like this :

```
$keywords = "test";
$keywords_Array = explode(',',$keywords);
$nbKeyword = count($keywords_Array);
$odm = $this->get("doctrine mongodb");
$donnees =  $odm->createQueryBuilder("MyBundle:MyCollection");
for($i=0; $i<$nbKeyword; $i++){
$donnees = $donnees->field('Field1')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/"Field5":'.$keywords_Array [$i].'/'));
}
$donnees = $donnees->getQuery()->execute();
Foreach($donnees  as $ data)
{
    $resp = $data->getResult();
}
Return $resp;
```

And for the second structure of data,the code should be like this :

```
 $keywords = "test";
 $keywords_Array = explode(',',$keywords);
 $nbKeyword = count($keywords_Array);
 $odm = $this->get("doctrine mongodb");
 $donnees =  $odm->createQueryBuilder("MyBundle:MyCollection");
 for($i=0; $i<$nbKeyword; $i++){       
$keys = new \MongoRegex("/".$keywords_Array [$i]."/");
    $donnees = $donnees->field("Field1")->in(array("Field2"=>$keys));
 }
 $donnees = $donnees->getQuery()->execute();
 Foreach($donnees  as $ data)
 {
    $resp = $data->getResult();
 }
 Return $resp;
```

Thank you.